# Three.js : Pan/move camera using mouse movement (without clicking)?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I want to be able to pan the pan the camera around my scene using the mouse. So far I've used TrackballControls to create this effect by click and dragging.

```
function init(){
  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45,window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
  camera.position.z = 500;

  controls = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera);
  controls.addEventListener('change', render);
}

function animate(){
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  controls.update();
}
```

Is there a way to be able to do this without having to click? Similar to [this site](https://tkmh.me)  ...

I have made [a codepen with my site](https://codepen.io/tknipe/full/gjoowv/) so far.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I worked it out :)

If anyone's trying to do the same thing I made the [following modifications to the TrackballControls.js file](https://www.diffchecker.com/TLjVgge3).